# Visual Studio modifying code item Timeplates: Get a certain format for the $time$ variable

Tags: code-templates

Currently I am modifying my IDE code itemtemplates because I always need to put some comments at the beginning of my script files. Which gets a bit annoying after some time.

**But I have bit of an issue with the $time$ variable. As far as I can understand there is more than one format the $time$ variable can express itself. So because I have a certain format like this XX/XX/XXXX - XX:XX. Where it suppose to be dd/mm/yyyy (like 2/04/2019) - HH:mm (10:20).**

I am looking it up how but I cannot see to find any documentation about it. Can anyone help me?